# adding ripple and on tap effect on my listtile

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add on tap effect and ripple effect on my code but when i try add "ink" its all turning red, i'm using flutter. here's my code '''
Expanded(

```
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
      
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.thermometerFull),
          title: Text("Temperature"),
          trailing:
              Text(temp != null ? temp.toString() + "\u00B0" : 'loading'),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.thermometerHalf),
          title: Text("feels like"),
          trailing: Text(feels != null ? feels.toString() : "loading"),
        ),
        ListTile(
          hoverColor: Color.fromRGBO(153, 255, 255, 10),
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.cloudMeatball),
          title: Text("Weather"),
          trailing: Text(desc != null ? desc.toString() : "loading"),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.sun),
          title: Text("Humidity"),
          trailing:
              Text(humidity != null ? humidity.toString() : "loading"),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind),
          title: Text("Wind speed"),
          trailing: Text(wind != null ? wind.toString() : "loading"),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.bug),
          title: Text("Wind speed"),
          trailing: Text(wind != null ? wind.toString() : "loading"),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind),
          title: Text("Wind speed"),
          trailing: Text(wind != null ? wind.toString() : "loading"),
        ), '''
```

can someone explain it in beginners way? this is my first try on flutter, thanks!

Comment: is your `ListView` inside a `Stack` ? Flutter currently has some problems with ripple animations when the widget is inside a stack. The ripple animation is then shown on the lowest layer. Try wrapping your `ListTile` inside a `Material`, that worked for me

Comment: And in general, such onTap ripple animations are activated by providing a function to the the `onTap` parameter of a widget. If `onTap` is `null` then the animation is deactivated

Answer (score 1):

ListTile already has `onTap` property and a inkwell effect on tap.

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` already has `onTap` property and an inkwell effect on tap, however you also have to provide `tileColor` to `ListTile`.

Example:

```
ListTile(
  tileColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade50,
  onTap: () {},
  title: Text("title"),
);
```